# How to through the token expired json or invalid token using laravel Passport API

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-passport

I am currently developing the Laravel web services using passport service provider for OAuth authentication purpose. But I want to know how to receive JSON like token expired or invalid URL, invalid token given request in Laravel application.

I am giving invalid token then shows the page not found html response but i need the invalid token or token expired message.

**ERROR**

> Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: Type error:
>   Argument 1 passed to
>   Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::addHeaders() must be
>   an instance of Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response, null given,
>   called in
>   E:\xampp\htdocs\projects\pet_clinic_api\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests.php
>   on line 61 in file
>   E:\xampp\htdocs\projects\pet_clinic_api\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests.php
>   on line 149 Stack trace: